# Rendering an edit partial form with bootstrap modals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal, partials

I am working on a Ruby on Rails project that has similar functionalities as dropbox. The gems I use:

> 1. carrierwave: Uploading files
> 2. acts_as_tree: Folder directory
> 3. slim: cleaner html
> 4. bootstrap 4

I am trying to incorporate bootstrap modals that renders the edit form so that users are able to edit the file_name attribute I have in my model.

```
- @documents.each do |document|
  = link_to document.file.filename, document.file.url
  b = document.file_name
  = number_to_human_size(document.file.size, :precision => 2)
  = document.content_type
  = document.updated_at
  = link_to "Download", document.file.url
  #renameButton.button.btn.btn-primary data-toggle="modal" data-target="#renameModal" Rename
  #renameModal.modal.fade tabindex="=1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"
    .modal-dialog role="document"
      .modal-content
        .modal-header
          #exampleModalLabel.h5.modal-title Rename folder
          button.close data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"
            span aria-hidden="true" &times;
        .modal-body
          = form_for document do |f|
            = f.label :name
            = f.text_field :file_name
            = f.submit
        .modal-footer
          button.btn.btn-outline-success data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" Close
          button.btn.btn-outline-danger Save changes
  = link_to "Delete", document, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete
```

The problem I have is that whenever I click on any of my "rename" button, the rendered edit form inside the modal always point to the first file entry instead of the selected one.

I think having a modal inside my do-loop causes this issue.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue could be that you are using same `data-target` for rename buttom click to open model and every Modal have same id

Try using an iterator to each id

```
data-target="#renameModal#{index}"
```

and also with your model id should be:

```
id: "#renameModal#{index}"
```

I dont know Much About slim Syntax use so please use your slim syntax.
This is just a basic Bootstrap Concept.

Hope This Helps...